# How do I access the value of this JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

What type of object is `container`?

```
var pname = "apples";
var extVal = "oranges";

var container = {};
container =
{
    presName: pname,
    presVal: pname
};
```

I want to compare the value of `presVal` (from inside `container`) to the value of `extVal`.

But I'm not sure how to access `presVal` to make this comparison.

Answer (score 4):

you can access properties of an object by using a dot, or putting it in [] so in your question :

```
if (container.parsVal===extVal) { ... }
```