# jQuery json decode

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.getJSON(
    "test.php",
    function(data){
        ... code should be here?
    }
)
```

`data` contains this code:

```
{
    "name": "Mary",
    "surname": "Carey"
}
```

I want to create these variables:

```
theName = name from json;
theSurname = surname from json;
```

What is a true syntax for this task?

Thanks.

Comment: `theName = data.name;
theSurname = data.surname;`

Comment: See the example in the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access the value of this JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445970/how-do-i-access-the-value-of-this-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot notation:

```
theName = data.name;
theSurname = data.surname;
```

or square-bracket notation:

```
theName = data['name'];
theSurname = data['surname'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
theName = data.name
theSurname = data.surname
```

… but it is probably better to keep them nicely wrapped up in `data` and just use that.

Answer (score 0):

The "data" should be a Javascript Object. If that is truly the data, you should be able to access it with data['name'] and data['surname'].

'dot' syntax should also work. (i.e. data.name and data.surname)